# javascript array sobreescrito

Tags: javascript, html, array

Tengo un problema muy curioso que no se por que sucede al rellenar un array en javascript.
El tema es que desde un json devuelto por un php, relleno un array y un select. La función hace lo que tiene que hacer, pero si elimino las líneas que rellenan el select el array se rellena de forma errónea.
Esta es la función que va bien:

```
function initdata(){
  $("#container").load("/html/new_user.html",function(){
      $('#idperiferico').empty();
      $('#idperiferico').append('<option value="">Seleccionar periferico</option>');
      $.post("/php/pyphp.php", { json:'{"command":"getperipherals"}' }, function(data){
         try {
             let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
             $.each(json_data, function(i) {
                let $option = $('<option />', { 
                   text:  json_data[i].nombre, 
                   value: i,
                });
                $('#idperiferico').append($option);  
                Window.data.peripheral.id=json_data[i].id;
                Window.data.peripheral.nombre=json_data[i].nombre;
                Window.data.peripheral.modelo=json_data[i].modelo;
                Window.data.peripheral.ip=json_data[i].ip;
                Window.data.peripheral.puerto=json_data[i].puerto;
                Window.data.peripheral.usuario=json_data[i].usuario;
                Window.data.peripheral.password=json_data[i].passwor;
                Window.data.perifericos.push(Window.data.peripheral);
            });
         }catch(error){
            alert("Error",error.message);
        }
     });
 });
}
```

y esta es la función que va mal:

```
function initdata(){
  $.post("/php/pyphp.php", { json:'{"command":"getperipherals"}' }, function(data){
         try {
             let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
             $.each(json_data, function(i) {
                Window.data.peripheral.id=json_data[i].id;
                Window.data.peripheral.nombre=json_data[i].nombre;
                Window.data.peripheral.modelo=json_data[i].modelo;
                Window.data.peripheral.ip=json_data[i].ip;
                Window.data.peripheral.puerto=json_data[i].puerto;
                Window.data.peripheral.usuario=json_data[i].usuario;
                Window.data.peripheral.password=json_data[i].passwor;
                Window.data.perifericos.push(Window.data.peripheral);
            });
         }catch(error){
            alert("Error",error.message);
        }
 });
}
```

El error, como decía, es que con la segunda versión de la función, que solo debería rellenar el array, el array se rellena con el numero de elementos correcto, pero todos son el ultimo elemento. No se si me explico.
Si el array tendría que ser array[1,2,3,4] queda array[4,4,4,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me sorprendería que el primer código no haga lo mismo que el primero: estás metiendo siempre el mismo objeto en el array:

```js
let dato = { atributo: 0 };

let array = [];

for (let i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
  dato.atributo = i;
  array.push(dato);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Lo que necesitas hacer es crear un objeto nuevo cada vez. De hecho, ni siquiera haría falta, viendo que la estructura es igual que la que tiene el json:

```
let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
//$.each es innecesario aquí, así es mucho más sencillo
json_data.forEach( function (peripheral) {
  Window.data.perifericos.push(peripheral);
});
```

Comment: Tal vez sea una errata, tal vez no... pero en principio el objeto no es el mismo: `Window.data.peripheral.password=json_data[i].passwor;`, si te fijas, el campo del json no lleva la *"d"* final :)

Comment: He asumido que es una errata

Comment: Perfecto, solucionado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes en el bucle

```
function initdata(){
  $.post("/php/pyphp.php", { json:'{"command":"getperipherals"}' }, function(data){
         try {
             let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
             $.each(json_data, function(i) {
                Window.data.peripheral.id=json_data[i].id;
                Window.data.peripheral.nombre=json_data[i].nombre;
                Window.data.peripheral.modelo=json_data[i].modelo;
                Window.data.peripheral.ip=json_data[i].ip;
                Window.data.peripheral.puerto=json_data[i].puerto;
                Window.data.peripheral.usuario=json_data[i].usuario;
                Window.data.peripheral.password=json_data[i].passwor;
ERROR --->      Window.data.perifericos.push(Window.data.peripheral);
            });
         }catch(error){
            alert("Error",error.message);
        }
 });
}
```

Debes ejecutar esa linea fuera del bucle y si no la ejecutas afuera, entonces comprueba que se ejecute en la ultima iteración, ejemplo:

```
function initdata(){
  $.post("/php/pyphp.php", { json:'{"command":"getperipherals"}' }, function(data){
         try {
             let json_data = JSON.parse(data);
             $.each(json_data, function(i) {
                Window.data.peripheral.id=json_data[i].id;
                Window.data.peripheral.nombre=json_data[i].nombre;
                Window.data.peripheral.modelo=json_data[i].modelo;
                Window.data.peripheral.ip=json_data[i].ip;
                Window.data.peripheral.puerto=json_data[i].puerto;
                Window.data.peripheral.usuario=json_data[i].usuario;
                Window.data.peripheral.password=json_data[i].passwor;
if(json_data.length==i+1){
    Window.data.perifericos.push(Window.data.peripheral);
    }
            });
         }catch(error){
            alert("Error",error.message);
        }
 });
}
```

Comment: sino logras obtener el tamaño con json_data.length, hay que ver que forma tiene tu json_data para obtenerlo correctamente.